Problem with horizontal collision in tile-based platformer
I'm developing a tile-based game. I encountered some unexpected behaviour in my collision code.
I don't want to post the whole code here. Because it's too long and might be painful to read (I am very sorry).
Basically, to detect and resolve collisions, I do this:
pseudocode:
// Resolve horizontal collisions
for tile in tiles:
    if checkCollision(tile.rect, player.rect):
        match tile.tileType:
            case Empty:
                continue

            case Platform, Wall:
                if player.velocity.x > 0.0:
                    intersect_rect = calculateIntersection(tile.rect, player.rect)
                    player.rect.x -= intersect_rect.width
                    player.velocity.x = 0.0

                elif player.velocity.x < 0.0:
                    intersect_rect = calculateIntersection(tile.rect, player.rect)
                    player.rect.x += intersect_rect.width
                    player.velocity.x = 0.0


// Resolve vertical collisions
for tile in tiles:
    if checkCollision(tile.rect, player.rect):
        match tile.tileType:
            case Empty:
                continue

            case Platform, Floor:
                if player.velocity.y > 0.0:
                    intersect_rect = calculateIntersection(tile.rect, player.rect)
                    player.rect.y = tile.rect.y - p.rect.height
                    player.velocity.y = 0.0

                elif player.velocity.y < 0.0:
                    intersect_rect = calculateIntersection(tile.rect, player.rect)
                    player.rect.y = tile.rect.y + tile.rect.height
                    player.velocity.y = 0.0

When I land on top of the platform, I got stuck a little bit, pressing A and D randomly teleport the player to the left side of the platform instantly.
I expect the player to be standing on top of the platform, but still move left and right normally.
I think the issue is the way I handle horizontal collisions, which makes the player's x velocity become zero and therefore make the player stuck.
Also, I think when my player gets stuck and then I pressed A or D, it will actually push my player back or forward because of those lines: player.rect.x -= intersect_rect.width and player.rect.x += intersect_rect.width.
This is making me confusing, because I tried adding different checks (only push the player up if he was falling, etc.) but nothing works. I appreciate all your response.

There is nothing in your conditions that indicated x or y until you get into the cases. In both of your loops you arbitrarily match Platform. You need to be more specific. Your first loop will make x adjustments even if the Platform collision is on the y axis. Also, why split this into 2 loops? That's not efficient.

Thank you very much for the kind comment. This may be the issue in my code. I'll try to fix it.

You may also want to consider that there is no reason for checkCollision to ever be True if the tile is Empty. It's almost like checkCollision is just always True. That defeats the purpose of checking for a collision.

Thanks for pointing that out! That's something I'd want to check.
